# Selendroid: Eclipse stuck, does not build

Tags: android, eclipse, memory, freeze, selendroid

I added "selendroid" to a fully working application, just created the driver and navigated to google using "selendroid".  Now eclipse is unable to build the app. 
It gets stuck, uses too much memory & CPU and nothing happens.

How do i make it work?  I have setup Android_home environment variable and also ran selendroid server.

Comment: Capitalize and punctuate better

Comment: You must be getting some information in form of verbose or error in command line. Please provide in detail your code snippet and the verbose from cmd.